# Powershell Get-ChildItem not returning all files in network folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I try to list the files in a network drive for further processing, but it seems Powershell misses out on some files:
Checking the Folder from Explorer in Windows, I see 61 items.
But when using Powershell

```
(Get-ChildItem  \\mynetworkdrive\myfolder\myfolderchild | Measure-Object).Count
```

It returns only 21, but I expected it to return the same result as Windows Explorer (61)
Also without using "Count", not all filenames get listed.
Anyone has an idea how Get-ChildItem will return all files?

Comment: `-Recurse -Force -File` maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference...
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -File \\mynetworkdrive\myfolder\myfolderchild | Measure-Object).Count
Still only 21 as a result

Comment: Could the reason be that it runs on a nearly now deprecated Windows 2012 Server?